# Why can I store an instance of a class which implements an interface "in" that interface without losing information?

Tags: java, syntax, casting

Let's have a look at this code:

```
package rpg;

interface A {
    // An empty interface
}

public class WarriorClass extends CharacterClass implements A {

    final int bab;
    public WarriorClass(int a) {
        bab = a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new WarriorClass(1);
        System.out.println(((WarriorClass) a).bab);
    }
}
```

First question: Why is it possible to use the interface `A` as the type of `a`?
Second question: Since A does not know about the iVar `bab` why does

```
System.out.println(((WarriorClass) a).bab);
```

print the correct value `1`?

Comment: I'm under the assumption that you are new to Java

Comment: You should read some Java literature...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not store the class "in" the interface. You are storing **a reference to the class** in a variable of the interfice class.

Java only works with references. All have the same length (like a pointer in C). The references are typed so you must assign to it an object of an appropiate class.

As for the relationship, extending a class or implementing an interface means that the new class objects belong also to the original class. So all objects are instances of `Object`. Since by extending/implementing you affirm that the new class follows the contract (specification) of the superclass/interface, they are do belong to it.

Answer (score 1):

How low do you want to go in the explanation?

Staying at the level of analogy, `A a` means "here's a place I can slot in anything which is a/implements A. There's a way of getting it to fit.

Since the object you created implements that interface, it'll work.

At this point, anything that can be done with any `A`, can be safely done with `a` (safe as in it won't make the whole thing fall to pieces, it can still throw an exception if e.g. `a` is null, but you can't trick the compiler into producing code that calls an `A` method on an object that doesn't have that method).

Later you cast to WarriorClass again with `((WarriorClass)a)`. This examines whatever happens to be in `a`. If it's null, the result is null. If it's an object that is indeed a `WarriorClass`, then the result is that object, accessed as such. If it's another implementation of `A`, there will be an exception.

At a level lower, in both cases there is a reference being stored at `a`. The compiler will makes sure you don't do something absolutely impossible (`A a = "abcde";` for example), and the reference is really just a number (everything is in computers after all) that lets it access that object.

When you call any `A` methods, that number is passed to the method, (it's where the `this` comes from), along with any parameters.

When you do the cast, the object is examined as described above. The result is another number (potentially the same one) that allows access to the object, but this time the program knows that the number refers to a `WarriorClass` (or to null). Hence it's possible for the code to call `.bab` on it. It can't lead to an impossible condition: If it is null, the normal check will find that, if `a` hadn't really been a `WarriorClass`, then that would have thrown when you tried to cast. At this point the program knows with 100% certainty that it can't be another class that also implements `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the first question: a variable can be declared as being of a type and instantiated as being of a sub-type of the declared one.

Answer for the second question: You are doing a cast, meaning that you explicitly say that the variable a is of the type you do the cast to, so you can use / call any variable or method that can be accessed in the context you are.